# Is there a trick to getting the gold or silver axe in Animal Crossing: City Folk?

Tags: animal-crossing-city-folk

I have been struggling for a couple of months now on getting an axe upgrade from [Serena](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Serena) in the fountain.  Succeeding with a new axe is at least partially a matter of luck, since on some days she doesn't even give me a chance to respond before taking my old axe and disappearing.  On other days, though, it feels like I'm just making the wrong decisions in the dialog tree.

Are there any choices that I should *always* make?  Alternatively, is there a general strategy to increase my chances of getting a silver or gold axe from her?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee a Golden or Silver axe, but yes, there are some guidelines:

- **Be honest.**  If she asks you if you threw in a Golden or Silver axe,  tell the truth and say you just threw in a plain one.
- **Be polite.**  If she asks you if you if you want something, say "Yes, **please**".

There is a more specific answer guide here: http://www.animalcrossingcommunity.com/accf_town_fountain_guide.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you should do is weed around the fountain, then put 10 flowers around the fountain. My lucky day is all ways sometime in January. Also, the answer to if you should try to sweet talk her, is yes. But be careful. Plus, if you eat cake in front of her fountain, she will get really mad, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's plain luck. She always says something different. sweet talk might work but, sometimes it makes worse.so there isn't anything you should ALWAYS say.